# Intensity reduce of captcha image overriding in magento 2

Tags: magento2.2.6

I have changed number of lines and dots in native magento 2 captcha in

```
/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Captcha/Image.php.
```

but not impact in captcha

Answer (score 2):

Tested in magento 2.3.4 working fine.

The DotNoiseLevel and LineNoiseLevel are set in **vendor\zendframework\zend-captcha\src\Image.php**

You can override **Magento\Captcha\Model\DefaultModel** and set DotNoiseLevel and LineNoiseLevel as **class DefaultModel extends \Magento\Captcha\Model\DefaultModel**

Your Custom module di.xml will be like below:

```
<preference for="Magento\Captcha\Model\DefaultModel" type="Custom\Captcha\Model\DefaultModel"/>
```

Your custom **DefaultModel** class need to extends **\Magento\Captcha\Model\DefaultModel** not the **\Zend\Captcha\Image**.

so updated class as below :

```
class DefaultModel extends \Magento\Captcha\Model\DefaultModel
{

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Session\SessionManagerInterface $session,
        \Magento\Captcha\Helper\Data $captchaData,
        \Magento\Captcha\Model\ResourceModel\LogFactory $resLogFactory,
        $formId
    ) {
        parent::__construct($session,$captchaData,$resLogFactory,$formId);
        $this->setDotNoiseLevel(1);
        $this->setLineNoiseLevel(1); 
    }    
}
```

Please check below screenshot after updated code.

[image]

Let me know if anyone have issue.

Comment: It's working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Tested in Magento 2.2
The DotNoiseLevel and LineNoiseLevel are set in `vendor\zendframework\zend-captcha\src\Image.php`
You can override `Magento\Captcha\Model\DefaultModel` and set DotNoiseLevel and LineNoiseLevel as `class DefaultModel extends \Zend\Captcha\Image`

Your Custom module di.xml will be

```
<preference for="Magento\Captcha\Model\DefaultModel" type="Custom\Captcha\Model\DefaultModel"/>
```

and model class will be
Custom\Captcha\Model\DefaultModel.php

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\Session\SessionManagerInterface $session,
    \Magento\Captcha\Helper\Data $captchaData,
    \Magento\Captcha\Model\ResourceModel\LogFactory $resLogFactory,
    $formId
) {
    parent::__construct($session,$captchaData,$resLogFactory,$formId);
    $this->setDotNoiseLevel(2);
    $this->setLineNoiseLevel(1);
}
```